# looking efficient algorithm for combinatorial problem

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to solve the following problem. Say you have set `S = {1,2,...n}`, set `T` of non-empty subsets of S, and integer `x > 0`. You want to know if it's possible to select one member from each subset in `T`, so that each member of `S` is selected at most `x` times.

```
Example 1:
S = {1,2,3,...,10}
T = {{1},{4,5},{1,2},{6,7,8},{4}}
x = 1
one solution would be {1,5,2,6,4}

Example 2:
S = {1,2,3,...,10}
T = {{1},{4,5},{1},{6,7,8},{4}}
x = 1
no solution since 1 would have to be selected twice
```

Here I have a python program that solves the problem, but can be very slow. (I'm not a computer scientist, but think the upper bound on the cost would be `n^m` where `m` is the size of `T`). I represent `T` as a 2d list of 0's and 1's, where each row in the list corresponds to a subset of `T`, each position in a row corresponds to a member of `S`, and the value in the position (either 0 or 1) corresponds to whether or not that member is present in the subset. For example, the row `[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]` would correspond to the subset `{2,3,4,7,9}`.

```
def f():

    t = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    solution_len = len(t)
    x = 3
    elem_counts = [0]*solution_len
    solution = [0]*solution_len # positions correspond to members of t, values correspond to members of s
    input_rows_len = len(t[0])
    a = 0
    t = sorted(t)

    while a <= solution_len:
        if a == solution_len:
            return solution[:solution_len]
        if solution[a] == input_rows_len:
            solution[a] = 0
            a -= 1
            if a == -1:
                return False
            elem_counts[solution[a]] -= 1
            solution[a] += 1
            continue
        bin_val = t[a][solution[a]]
        if elem_counts[solution[a]] == x or bin_val == 0:
            solution[a] += 1
        else:
            elem_counts[solution[a]] += 1
            a += 1
    return False
```

Comment: Don't simply dump your code on us: post a human-friendly description of your algorithm.  I don't relish the idea of trying to reverse-engineer the algorithm from code with one-letter variable names, generic labels, and "magic" numbers.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have included the code (I'm not looking for someone to analyze it). I'm just concerned if the problem is clear and want to see if it reduces to something for which there is a known, efficient algorithm.

Comment: and btw, the one-letter variable names, correspond to those that are in the description of the problem

Answer (score -1):

there is a library that I used once for a similar combinatorial problem. I had the same issue of performance and this library is fast. it's called python-constraint. here is the link: https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/

you simply create a problem object, add variables, and then add certain constraints to the object and finally get the solutions.